# Issues with Revolution R Open + Yosemite + Sublime Text

Tags: r, sublimetext2, sublimerepl, rro

I have installed RRO on a new macbook pro 13" retina (two cores) & Yosemite.

I tried with RSTUDIO and R 25 (S. Urbinek notorious benchmark) and I got the test time down from ~31 s to a blazing 5 s (thanks to multithreading and Intel MKL).  Marvellous!

The problems are with Sublime text.  I use Sublime text 3 as text console more often than rstudio for a variety of reasons.

I use it in conjunction with the package R-Box to drive where I want to send the code to: either to the R console, or with SublimeREPL R to direct the code to Sublime itself splitting the screen in two and sending the code to the right hand of the screen where I run the R console.

Normally I configure R-Box user settings with R,  and SublimeREPL specifying the R path as /usr/bin/R (see below).

Results (sadly)

- R-Box & R does not work:  it cannot find the RRO app (even changing
  the name of the app from RRO to R it does not find it).
- R-Box & SublimeREPL (i.e. the
  console in the right side of the screen) shows the console OK, but there is no 
  visible prompt, hence it is of no use.

These are the R scripts that work with CRAN R:

```
# R-Box
{
    "App": "R",
    "osx":
    {
        "App": "SublimeREPL"
    }

}
# SublimeREPL
{
    "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH};/usr/bin/R"},
    "show_transferred_text": true

}
```

(I posted this also on the RRO forun at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rropen/bK_YPqxhXsI)

PS: could somebody with tagging power create a tag for RRO (Revolution R Open)?

Comment: Try finding RRO in the path `/Library/Frameworks/`

Comment: @Andrie thanks for the tag.  As I said in my post, SublimeREPL find R (i.e. RRO) and displays in the console, but the cursor is missing. Why R is not found by R-Box (in the other modality) is more mysterious.

Comment: Hacked / resolved the second problem.  Apparently SublimeREPL RRO  wants a setting of "echo = true", but in the file at ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/R is set to false. Not sure how to set it from the Sublime console though.

Comment: Can you please add this information as an answer and mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issues with R-Box is resolved changing `RRO` app name to `R.app` (alias didn't work and I had explicitly to change the name of the app).

As in my comment above, the second issue with SublimeREPL is resolved changing the setting  of

```
echo = true
```

in the file at `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/R` (otherwise set to false).

As the change it is not in a file "customisable" in the console one needs to probably change it at any new release of SublimeREPL.